# Change MySQL Root Password in XAMPP

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, xampp

I've got XAMPP working on my Windows 10 machine. It seems that PHPMyADmin only works if the DB has no password. I'd really prefer to set a password for the root DB account.

I went into the XAMPP control panel -> User Accounts -> Edit Privileges for the root account.

When I enter in a new password and hit 'go', I refresh the page and it says that it can't connect. Is there any way to set the root DB password for XAMPP in such a way that it does not break PHPMyAdmin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open **C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin** folder, and then open **config.inc.php**:

And then, change the line like this:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config'; //change this to cookie from config
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
```

To:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
```

And login with blank password, and go to SQL tab, and run this:

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'MyNewPass'
```